# Можно ли поместить внутрь if цикл while?

Tags: javascript

Правильно ли я написал этот код? Я новичок в JavaScript... Но вроде же должно работать...

```js
var scoops = 5;
var kokos = 8;
if (kokos == 8) {
  while (scoops > 1) {
    document.write("LIKE IT");
    scoops = scoops - 1;
  } else {
    document.write("DON'T LIKE")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде закралась ошибка: у вас оператор else стоит после блока `while(..){..}`, а не после блока `if(..){...}`.

Правильно будет в приведенном ниже блоке. В чем не трудно убедиться, нажав на клавишу Выполнить после блока кода.

```js
var scoops = 5;
var kokos = 8;
if (kokos == 8) {
  while (scoops > 1) {
    document.write("LIKE IT!");
    scoops = scoops - 1;
  }
} else {
  document.write("DON'T LIKE!")
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь всё понятно.

Answer (score 0):

он и после **if** если будет стоять, то не будет работать.... у вас после выполнения кода - 4 раза **LIKE IT!** и не разу **DON'T LIKE!**. **While** понижает *scoops* до единицы и не передаёт управление **if** больше (**else** не выполняется)...
У меня таже беда и тоже интересно почему...

```
function stepen(){
    a=+prompt(`Введите число `);
    c=Math.floor(prompt(`Введите степень числа `+a)); //округляем до целого, если введена дробь
     if(isNaN(a)||isNaN(c)){alert(`Это не число!`)    //если ввели строки
     }else if(c<0){             //отсеивает введение минусового числа степени
        while (c<0||isNaN(c)) {
            alert(`Число не должно быть меньше нуля!`);
            c=Math.floor(+prompt(`Введите степень числа `+a));
        }
    } else document.write(a+`<sup>${c}</sup> = `+Math.pow(a,c));
}
stepen();
```